# PDF digital signature

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I have a c# winform app that generates some PDF memos.

Every logged user into the system can generate the PDFs. Right now each memo has a signature space where a digital sign (image) of the real ink user signature is placed.

I'm using `ComponentOne C1Report`.

I want to replace that with a digital signature but I have the following questions:

1. How can I create a different digital signature for each user logged (because what I was reading is that I require a certificate).
2. How type of string or format does a digital signature in a PDF looks like?

Comment: Just updated. My question is if I have to generate a digital certificate for each of my system users?

Comment: Do your users already [get certificates assigned to them by the Domain when they log in](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c6tHK.png)? Using that certificate would be the best one. If you currently don't have a certificate perhaps you should talk with the local IT about setting a certificate system up. It should not be your programs responsibility to generate a new certificate, you need to make sure the infrastructure is in place that each user will have a certificate already in their store assigned to them.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is a Cloud Application so they dont log using any domain. Any clue on how to work around this?

Comment: In addition to @ScottChamberlain comment you should understand why you are trying to sign forms. Whoever made the requirement should know what type of signatures are expected (if any).

Comment: What is the digital signing for? Is it for non-repudiation by the author? Or is it to prevent later unwanted changes? In the former case you need one certificate per user and a mechanism guaranteeing that no one else but him can use the associated private key. In the latter case a single certificate managed by your application suffices (in that case your application would be the signer even though the in-document visualizations of the signatures could still show the *real ink user signature*).

Comment: Who shall be able to verify the signatures? If just a limited number of people whom you can ask to install a given certificate as trust anchor in their Adobe Reader, you can create the certificates yourself. If you cannot ask all potential verifiers to change the settings of their Adobe Reader before verifying, you need certificates from a certificate authority by default trusted by all potential verifiers. This may be an internal CA of an organization all verifiers belong to or some CA on a trusted list used by Adobe Reader by default.